# How to loop through a table and grab a row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop

What I'm trying to accomplish is to loop through all the rows of table and grab one row at a time and do something with it. Something like this

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE countmax INT; 
    DECLARE id INT;
    DECLARE name VARCHAR(255);
    SET x = 1;
    SET id = 0;
    SET countmax = (select count(*) from Appian.APPIAN_DATA);
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

    WHILE x < countmax DO
        SET name = (SELECT FULL_NAME
                    FROM Appian.APPIAN_DATA 
                    WHERE ID = x
                    );
        #do something with above result here later.
        SET x = x + 1;

    END WHILE;
    select name;

END
```

From above, name returns null. I checked if x is being incremented properly and it seems to be fine. I want to grab the row whee ID = x.
First time using loops in SQL so not sure what's allowed and what's not. However, I haven't seen people using selects inside a loop, mostly manipulating data and updating rows. Eventually the goal will be to create temp table and insert each row into it after manipulation. For the experts, what dumb thing am I doing here that I can't pull the data from the table and assign it to the variable?
Edit: updated code to be a bit more clear

Comment: Why do this all in the database? This is what application layers are for. This loop code also makes zero sense to me. Why fetch the exact same value N times and then return it once?

Comment: Doesn't this just boil down to `SELECT FULL_NAME FROM Appian.APPIAN_DATA`?

Comment: because I don't want to do it using excel anymore with such large amounts of data. We are just trying to create an improvement without an overkill of creating a full front-end, which would also be very slow.  But since DBs are meant to process large amounts of data we are just trying to move the excel work over to the database. Also, I'm only fetching the same value multiple times for testing as I mentioned. Ideally I would pull the value of every row, ID = x

Comment: Excel is not the application layer I'm talking about, I mean "application" in the [OSI sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) where in the database world it means roughly "code running on top of the database through an external connection". If you're a Microsoft shop I mean like C#, or any language that can interface with MySQL directly.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted would only look at ID = 379 , I assume you meant to use "WHERE ID = x".

Also, you can usually accomplish what you want without having to use a loop, but if you insist on an iterative programing consider learning cursors instead.  It will take care of a the little details within a while loop for you with much simpler syntax.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: This presumes IDs are issued sequentially and without holes, which is a huge assumption to make. Just because `COUNT(*)` is 100 doesn't mean the IDs are 1..101.

Comment: Very true, another reason a cursor would be a better choice for iterative programing.  You would simply set the cursor to fetch each ID and Name then do your something with the results.

Comment: Thanks, if I the return result is ordered by ID then that would not be a problem, except where a row has been deleted and there is a gap. But giving cursor another chance and using the loop function I think I can make it work now. I was using it wrong before so I stopped but I figured out what my error was